# Question regarding Polynomial division

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

My understanding of division in general is this:

dividend / divisor = quotient

The quotient X divisor will give you the dividend.

So if we had an equation:

$(x - 2)\left){\vphantom{1{2{x^3} - 11x + 6}}}\right.
\!\!\!\!\overline{\,\,\,\vphantom 1{{2{x^3} - 11x + 6}}}$

If we just address the $2{x^3}$ expression: How is it that $2{x^3} \div x$ would give you the same quotient as $2{x^3} \div (x - 2)$, i.e.:

$\eqalign{
  & 2{x^3} \div (x - 2) = 2{x^2}  \cr 
  & 2{x^3} \div (x) = 2{x^2} \cr} $

Surely the (x-2) answer has to be different to the answer where you are just dividing by x?
I know I havent unravelled some big fallacy in division, I'd just like to understand it and I'd love for someone to explain where I'm going wrong, thank you.

Comment: First of all, division in general has a *remainder*. Second, what makes you think $2x^3$ divided by $x-2$ is, or should be, $2x^2$?

Comment: $2{x^3} \div (x - 2) = 2{x^2}$ remainder $4x^2$. i.e. $2{x^3} \div (x - 2) = 2{x^2}+\frac{4x^2}{x-2}$. This can be divided further to give $2x^2+4x+8$ remainder $\frac{16}{x-2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gerry Myerson says, division in general has a *remainder*.  You don't have $$\text{dividend} \div \text{divisor} = \text{quotient}\tag1$$ unless the remainder is zero.  In general, what you have is $$\text{dividend} = (\text{quotient}\times\text{divisor}) + \text{remainder}$$
and when the remainder is zero, it simplifies to (1).  For example, we can't say $$100 \div 7 = 14$$ which is wrong, but we can say that $$100 = (14\cdot 7) + 2.\tag2$$  The 2 here is the remainder.

There's a theorem, often just called [the division theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_theorem), that holds in a great many situations, and says that for any $a$ and $b\ne 0$, there are a unique quotient $q$ and remainder $r$ such that $$a = qb+r$$ where (this is important) $r$ is in some sense "smaller" than $b$.   When $a$ and $b$ are integers, "smaller" can be understood to mean that $|r| < |b|$; in (2) above we had $r=2$ and $b=7$ so we did indeed have $|r|<|b|$.  When $a$ and $b$ are polynomials, "smaller" is a little different: it means that the *degree* of $r$ is less than the *degree* of $b$.

Now what's $2x^3 \div (x-2)$?  Here the division theorem tells us that we can find quotient $q$ and remainder $r$ such that $$2x^3 = q(x-2) + r$$ and the degree of $r$ is less than the degree of $x-2$.  That is, $r$ is a constant.  In this case the solution has

$$2x^3 = (2x^2+4x+8)(x-2) + 16$$

The remainder is 16, not zero, because $x-2$ does not divide evenly into $2x^3$; this is analogous to the way that $7$ does not divide evenly into $100$ and leaves a remainder of 2.  On the other hand $2x^3$ does divide evenly by $x$ because the remainder is zero; we have

$$2x^3 = 2x^2\cdot x + 0$$

and again the degree of the remainder, 0, is less than the degree of the divisor, $x$.  In this case we also have the opposite equation

$$2x^3\div x = 2x^2.$$

When we work in a context called a "field", such as the rational numbers, then everything always divides, and the remainder guaranteed by the division theorem is always zero.  Going  back to our $100\div 7$ example, if we are working in the rationals instead of in the integers, then the quotient and remainder guaranteed by the division theorem are $\frac{100}{7}$ and $0$, and we have $$100 = \frac{100}{7}\cdot 7 + 0.$$  Since the remainder is $0$, we can also say $$100\div 7 = \frac{100}7.$$

Comment: [Polynomial long division](https://enwp.org/Polynomial_long_division). It is completely analogous to integer long division: you start by estimating what monomial $M_2$ will make $M_2\cdot(x-2) \approx 2x^3$.  The answer is clearly $M_2 = 2x^2$.  Then you subtract $M_2\cdot(x-2) = 2x^3 - 4x^2$ from the divisor $2x^3$, obtaining a remainder $R_2 =4x^2$, and repeat the process, again finding a monomial $M_1$ that makes $M_1\cdot(x-2)\approx 4x^2$, and so on. The remainder decreases at each stage. At the end, the quotient is $M_2+M_1+M_0$ and the final remainder $R_0$ is the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

The same way multiplication is addition many times, division is subtraction many times. When you do long division you are trying to subtract the divisor from the dividend as many times as you can, until you cannot do it any further.

For example: If we try to divide $47$ by $2$. In long division we take the $4$ and divide it by $2$, i.e. we know that we can subtract $2$, two times from $4$. We know that that $4$ is actually representing a $40$ in that $47$, when we use decimal notation. This is how decimal notation works: $47=4\cdot 10+7$. Then we really subtract $2\cdot 10$ times $2$ from $47$. We get $7$, and then it is easy to see we can still subtract $2$ another extra $3$ times. In total we subtracted $2$, $2\cdot10+3$ times. So $47=2\cdot 23+1$.

Polynomials are pretty much the same as decimal notation, just replace the $10$ by an $x$: as if we write $4x+7$ instead of $4\cdot 10 +7$. Notice how the procedure we did above also gives you the division of $4x+7$ by $2$.

For numbers of more digits (and polynomials of higher degree) it works similarly. You try to *subtract* as much as possible (you do it as much as possible to be as efficient as possible. This is of course not the only way to divide number or polynomials. There are also other ways to try to be efficient). That is why you try to subtract as much as possible the terms of higher degree (as with numbers you try to subtract the digit that is multiplied by the higher power of $10$ in decimal notation).

Comment: So, when you multiply the polynomial $x$ by the polynomial $x$, you are adding $x$ to itself $x$ times? I don't see any way to make sense of that.

Comment: Don't worry. Not everybody is good at generalizing ideas.

Comment: Ways to make sense of that: No1: Polynomials are determined by their values at the integers (actually you only need as many values as their degree). So you can make sense of it as '$x$ times' meaning actually times, where you replace $x$ by integers in large enough set, or perhaps all integers.

Comment: No2: Purely symbolic, as a direct generalization of the procedure of Euclidean division, to that of polynomials. This way you get the notion of Euclidean domain in general. Replacing the role of the absolute value in the integers by the degree function in the polynomials.

Comment: I can do without the condescension. How do you interpret $\sqrt2\times\sqrt3$ as "addition many times"? You may also want to have a look at Keith Devlin's many columns on this topic, beginning with http://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_01_10.html and working your way backwards. But I suppose you don't think Devlin is much good at generalizing ideas.

Comment: If you don't want condescension, begin by not assuming that a post written in simple terms is by someone that doesn't know what he/she is talking about. Read again my comments (the No1) and you will see that there is no need to interpret $\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{3}$ as addition many times, to be able to interpret polynomial multiplication as certain form of addition many times. Once you know how to multiply the coefficients, multiplication by $x$ could be understood as $x$ times, for every natural number replacing $x$.

Comment: You are right, the article you link is simply making a storm where there is simply none. Multiplication of natural numbers IS iterated addition, that iterated addition is not suitable for defining it for other numbers has nothing to do with it. If you put more objects to which define the operation, why in the world would you expect to be able to use exactly the same definition?

Comment: Finally, what I found was the main difficulty of the OP was understanding why, if we are dividing whole polynomials, the algorithm instead divides only the leading coefficients. This is a very common question, I myself had it the first time I saw long division. My answer is trying to address this question, in the simplest language I imagined. MJD also added later a bit to answer this in a comment to his answer. Do you have something interesting to add? Add it. Instead of making ridiculous objections.

Comment: You wrote, "multiplication is addition many times". You didn't write, "multiplication of natural numbers is addition many times". I regret having assumed that you meant what you wrote, rather than something more sensible than what you wrote. And I'm sure Professor Devlin, who insists that "multiplication is not, repeat not, repeated addition. Not even for positive whole numbers," will be happy to discuss your opinions with you. Why not write to him?

Comment: I have no interest in writing to him. It is you who is going around making stupid objections that add nothing to the understanding of neither the question or my answer. I am pretty sure you read that article and didn't quite understand the point. The point is didactical. The only thing anyone has to do to show that addition of naturals is iterated addition is to put three rows of 5 dots and count there are 15 dots. When real numbers are interpreted as lengths then this interpretation of multiplication is inconvenient. When real numbers are interpreted as sequences of natural numbers, ...

Comment: ... as when you write them in decimal notation, then you can workout again multiplication as iterated addition. This last, the decimal notation, is the one more similar to how polynomials work, or power series etc. See? When you don't keep you mind squared, you can generalize easily and get ideas from one part of mathematics to another. Ridiculous objections are only good for when you are writing a text book.

Comment: [tetration http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration], [hyperoperation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation], ... it is the idea of multiplication as iterated addition what leads to this generalizations, to this new mathematics, new notation. The fact of this idea being didactically (arguably) inconvenient as the way to see multiplication of numbers is an entirely different business. To do mathematics it is best not to keep the head square as a block.